# Woocommerce set_price function inconsistency

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am testing a woocommerce hook that updates my cart, when a form is submitted.

The code below works fine, and sets the cart item to 40, note I only have one item in the cart for testing.

However when i change it to set_price($new_price), it does not update the price to the new price in the new_price variable. And when I var_dump the variable, it outputs a string type with the correct price that needs to be updated. At first I thought I had to convert the $new_price var from string to int or number as the Post var is a string. But when checking the Woocommerce docs it seems that the set_price function takes a string as parameter.

https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productset_price/

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_item_price', 999, 1 );

function change_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    $new_price=$_POST['item_meta'][19];
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        var_dump($new_price);
        $item['data']->set_price(40);
    }
}
```

Thanks Julian

Comment: Your posted data need to be set in a WC_Session variable before, and then you will call that WC_Session variable in your code, to change the cart item price.

Comment: I ended up setting a php session variable.

Answer (score 0):

LoicTheAztec was correct I needed a session variable.